# child component is not rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have created a simple child component in a react application. Below is the child component code.

```js
import React from 'react';

class work extends React.Component{   

    createList=()=>{
        let work=[];
        for(let item=0;item<52;item++){
            work.push(<li>{item}</li>);
        }
        return work;
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <ul>
                {this.createList}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default work;
```

While running my application I am getting error. `Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it`

What is the issue with my code?

Comment: missing `()` - fn call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error explanation is quite clear: you are giving the  a function as a child, which is not expected. Just replace `{this.createList}` with `{this.createList()}`